# Create a table in dbshell with django

Tags: sql, python-3.x, django

here is my code :

```
frontgreat=> CREATE TABLE contact_titlemessagesuggestion;
ERROR:  syntax error at or near ";"
LINE 1: CREATE TABLE contact_titlemessagesuggestion;
```

i don't understand why it's not working and why it's an syntax error.

```
frontgreat=> DROP TABLE contact_titlemessagesuggestion;
ERROR:  table "contact_titlemessagesuggestion" does not exist
```

have no syntax error and work fine.

Regards

Comment: Exactly which SQL dialect is this?

Comment: Most databases require tables to have *at least* one column, so `CREATE TABLE foo ( bar INT );` for example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can normally not create a table without any columns. Therefore one often either has to list the columns, or use for example a query that provides both data (but meta-data as well) to construct the columns in the table.

For example:

```
CREATE TABLE contact_titlemessagesuggestion (
    pk INT
);
```